# date and time formating in ASP.NET Data Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I need to format the date and time in binding expression in the following format

day/month/year hour:minute:second AM/PM
01/10/2013 01:05:13 AM

what i tried so far is

```
Eval("Date", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}")
```

but this only format the date not the time, Even i don't see the time.

Comment: Well you have not mentioned any time formatting like `{0:dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}`, What you say if just format it with day, month and year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Eval("Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")
```